# Node-mocks-https throwing build issue after node 18 upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, node-mocks-http, mockhttpmessagehandler

I have a requirement to migrate to node 18 from 16 for node application.
am getting below error while npm run test

/apps/node_modules/node-mocks-http/lib/mockRequest.js: Unexpected token * (550:54)

mockRequest[Symbol.asyncIterator] = async function* asyncIterator() {

Npm test works fine with node 16. I have tried downgrading node-mocks-http package. But no luck.
this is my package structure

```
    
    "body-parser": "~1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^3.5.0",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.9.0",
    "jsforce": "^1.11.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.35",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.0",
    "request": ">=2.81.0",
    "rx": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
    "salesforce-jwt-bearer-token-flow": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-node": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/debug": "0.0.30",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/jest": "^22.1.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^1.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-ts": "^0.2.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.10.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "nyc": "^11.3.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "proxyquire": "^1.8.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "^22.0.4"
  }
```